# What material is Prusa mk3s+ hotend heaterblock made of?

Tags: prusa-i3, hotend, replacement-parts

My heaterblock is in a poor state after the heater malfunction. Before I'll buy a spare, I want to ask what material is the [original block](https://www.prusa3d.com/product/hotend-heaterblock-e3d/) made of? I don't see it on the product page.

Available spares and replacements are made of aluminum, brass, and copper, the latter two in plated and not plated versions. Original is, obviously, aluminum or plated something. Aluminum 3rd party replacements are 10 times cheaper than brass or copper ones. So, before I'll buy expensive one, I want to know if I really have to.

If original is aluminum, the supplemental question would be why to buy plated copper despite the price difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Aluminum

At 9.20 grams (around 0.32 ounces) including screws and some soot I wasn't able to clean out, it can't be anything but aluminum.

[image: Photo of the block on a scale]